# CSS Two columns, one relative one fixed, min-width on relative?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a left content, right fixed image layout, but if i make the left column (which contains all the content) a relative positioning with 60% width, and the right column as a 40% width relative positioning (which contains the fixed image div inside of it) the fixed image still overlaps the content to the left when the viewport shrinks horizontally.

http://dev.curran-connors.com/freelance/ironmountain-2014/ceo-letter.php

Shrink the viewport down horizontally, you will see that the right side image overlapping the text when it gets smaller. Does anyone know how to create a min-width for the content, and allow the overflow to scroll horizontally? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RoToRa - That comment came off rude and not constructive. Try to help him/her instead of putting him/her down. thamind - position: relative does two things: 1. Makes any absolutely positioned child elements positioned relative to the position: relative container. 2. Allows you to shift the position of the position: relative element relative to where it would normally be in the flow layout. E.g. top: -5px would move it up 5px from where it would normally be without position: relative. Might want to review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @RoToRa I know exactly what relative positioning does. What I'm trying to say is that in this case, it doesn't work. What I would like to know is if there is something *like* this that would make the formatting work.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley Thanks for the input, but this still doesn't go anywhere near answering the question I had originally stated.

Comment: Then perhaps we don't understand the question as it's stated. When I resize the window, the image on the right does not overlap the content on the left. The content simply resizes/reorganizes to accommodate until the "bg-rt" div reaches it's min-width and the viewport adds a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley That was the fix I came up with. I was trying not to resort to a media query but I used that and made the change about 5 days ago. Thanks for your input though

Answer (score 0):

Small changes in CSS might solve the issue.
Replace the below css classes and it will work.

```css
.ceoLetter {
/* min-width: 760px; */
position: relative;
width: 60%;
z-index: 750;
}

.ceo-letter .rightCol {
bottom: 0;
float: right;
padding: 50px 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 56px;
height: 95%;
width: 40%;
/* min-width: 485px; */
background-color: rgba(0, 71, 130, 0.75);
z-index: 2;
}

.ceo-letter .ceo-bg-rt {
background: url("img/building-rt-bl.jpg") no-repeat scroll right top /cover;
right: 0px;
top: 56px;
height: 95%;
width: 100%;
/* min-width: 485px; */
z-index: 9;
/* position: fixed; */
}

.rightCol {
position: relative;
/* max-width: 425px; */
z-index: 9;
height: 100%;
width: 40%;
}
```